# javascript calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

I was wondering if there was a simple way to make a topdown list calendar for a website. I don't want to use the google calendar. I would also want the calendar to show like the next 5 events and hide the rest until the 5 shown have already happened. If there is a way to do this with jquery I wouldn't mind doing that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good starting point:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cutindex1a.shtml

Just about every layout for a calender structure, and then event-show limiting etc could be implemented by you at the end.  At the least it'll give you a base with which to work from.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm looking for something like a to-do list type..not the monthly type...sort of like the html example on this webpage (its just html not javascript.) 

http://theoew.uuuq.com/RPCA/

that part in the sidebar called upcoming events.